# How can I reduce the repetiveness in my code?

Tags: java, applet, japplet

Look at the following program:

```
public class HouseOfCards 
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        for (int cards = 1; cards <= 4; cards++)
        {
           if (cards == 1) 
           {
               System.out.println("Ace of Clubs");
                for (int singles = 2; singles <= 9; singles++)
                { 
                   System.out.println(singles + " of Clubs");
                }//end of for loop()
               System.out.println("Jack of Clubs");
               System.out.println("Queen of Clubs");
               System.out.println("King of Clubs");
               System.out.println("Ace of Clubs");
          }//end of if() 
                            ......
             //More else if() blocks for each suit
                            ......
        }//end of for loop()
     }//end of method main() 
   }//end of class HouseOfCards
```

In the above code, I want to print the first set of cards, that being clubs, then do the same for the rest of the suits in a "new deck order" format.

Clubs --> Spades --> Hearts --> Diamonds

I see that the first if() block, that being, (cards == 1), is a little repetitive. I don't want to do 4 if blocks to do the whole deck.

**My questions to you are as follows,
1. how would I go about reducing the code in that way? 
2. Is it possible? 
Or
3. is it just best to do 4 sets of if() blocks for each suit?**

Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make array of it:
`String[] arr = new String[]{"clubs","spades","hearts","diamonds"}`
then use loop:
`for(int i=0;i<arr.length;i++){}`
example:

```
public class HouseOfCards 
{
    private static final String[] arr = new String[]{"Clubs","Spades","Hearts","Diamonds"};
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
            for(int i=0;i<arr.length;i++)
            {
            System.out.println("Ace of "+arr[i]);
                for (int singles = 2; singles <= 9; singles++)
                { 
                   System.out.println(singles + " of "+arr[i]);
                }//end of for loop()
               System.out.println("Jack of "+arr[i]);
               System.out.println("Queen of "+arr[i]);
               System.out.println("King of "+arr[i]);
               System.out.println("Ace of "+arr[i]);
           }//end of if()
     }//end of method main() 
   }//end of class HouseOfCards
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I found that to be the best way to go about it!

Answer (score 2):

```
private String[] cards = { "Ace", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five", "Six", "Seven", "Eight", "Nine", "Ten", "Jack", "Queen", "King"};
private String[] colors = {"Clubs", "Spades", "Hearts", "Diamonds"};
```

Then iterate through both array using for loops.

```
for (int iColor = 0; iColor < colors.length; iColor++) {
    for (int iCard = 0; iCard < cards.length; iCard++) {
        System.out.printf("%s of %s%n", cards[iCard], colors[iColor];
    }
}
```

Comment: This seems to be the most minimalistic approach to my problem. Thanks for your input!

Answer (score 1):

If the only problem you have is printing the suit, then I would either create an array:

```
String[] suits = {"Clubs", "Spades", "Hearts", "Diamonds"};
```

or an `ArrayList<String>()`:

```
ArrayList<String> suits = new ArrayList<String>();
suits.add("Clubs");
suits.add("Spades");
suits.add("Hearts");
suits.add("Diamonds");
```

You can simply iterate it like that:

```
for(String suit : suits)
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a method `printSuit(String suitName)` and use it inside each `if` statement.

You can also create `Enum` of suits and iterate over its values.

Answer (score 0):

For algorithm understanding purpose :

If you have a `For` with X values and inside a `if` for each values, than just remove the `for` and the `if`.

```
for (int cards = 1; cards <= 4; cards++){
       if (cards == 1) System.out.println("A");
       if (cards == 2) System.out.println("B");
       if (cards == 3) System.out.println("C");
       if (cards == 4) System.out.println("D");
}
```

is exactly the same as :

```
System.out.println("A");
System.out.println("B");
System.out.println("C");
System.out.println("D");
```

Answer (score 0):

To use `enum` would be best in your case with extra function.
Here is my aproach to make your code simple.

```
public static void main(String...args){
    for(Card card : Card.values()){
        showCards(card);
    }
}
static void showCards(Card card){
    for(CardVal cv : CardVal.values()){
        System.out.println(cv + " of "+card);
    }
}
static enum Card {
    Club, 
    Spades,
    Hearts,
    Diamond
}
static enum CardVal {
    Ace,
    Two,
    Three,
    Four,
    Five,
    Six,
    Seven,
    Eight,
    Nine,
    Ten,
    Jack,
    Queen,
    King
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A more object-oriented solution would be to create a Card class, and promote suit and value to enumerated types as such:

```
public class Card {

    public enum Suit {
        HEARTS,
        CLUBS,
        SPADES,
        DIAMONDS;
    }

    public enum FaceValue {
    ACE,
    KING,
    QUEEN,
    JACK,
    TEN,
    NINE,
    EIGHT,
    SEVEN,
    SIX,
    FIVE,
    FOUR,
    THREE,
    TWO,
    ONE
    }

    private Suit suit;
    private FaceValue value;

    public Card(Suit suit, FaceValue value) {
        this.suit = suit;
        this.value = value;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return value.toString() + " of " + suit.toString();
    }

}
```

Then you can reduce your printing code to two nested loops:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    for(Suit s : Suit.values()) {
        for (FaceValue v : FaceValue.values()) {
            System.out.println(new Card(s,v));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As java is object oriented language, try to think objects

first create Enums with colours and ranks;

```
    enum Colour{
        Clubs,Diamonds,Hearts,Spades;
    }

    enum Rank{
         Two, Three, Four, Five, Six, Seven, Eight, Nine, Ten, Jack, Queen, King,Ace
    }
```

Define your card

```
class Card{
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return rank + " of "+colour;
    }
    public Card(Colour colour, Rank rank) {
        super();
        this.colour = colour;
        this.rank = rank;
    }
    private final Colour colour;
    private final Rank rank;

}
```

it will be good if your card will implements comparable interface, then if you try to create any card game it might be useful

and last what you need is deck

```
class Deck{
    List<Card> cards = new ArrayList<Card>();       
    public Deck(){
        for (Colour colour : Colour.values()){
            for (Rank rank : Rank.values()){
                cards.add(new Card(colour, rank));
            }   
        }
    }
}
```

deck when instantiated creates all cards, it can be usefull to manipulate cards